# Получить атрибут data через JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

У меня есть такой HTML код, где кнопка "Удалить" выводиться циклом в PHP и хранит data-атрибут user-id.
Когда я пытаюсь получить этот id в JQuery, то мне выводиться только id первой записи. То есть, при клике на остальные кнопки "Удалить" я получаю всегда одно значение data-user-id.

Как это исправить, помогите пожалуйста

```js
// Удаление записи

$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#btn-delete').click(function(e) {
        console.log($('.btn-delete').data('user-id'));
        
    });
});
```

```html
 <td>
    <button class="btn btn-delete popup-open" data-user-id="<?= $user['id']; ?>" >Удалить</button>
</td>
```

Comment: `$('.btn-delete')` != `$('#btn-delete')`

Comment: `console.log(e.target.dataset.userId);` или `console.log($(e.target).data('user-id'));`

Comment: Забыл уточнить, $('.btn-delete') - это сама кнопка "Удалить", хранящая дата атрибут, а $('#btn-delete') - это кнопка в модальном окне, она ничего не хранит

Comment: @KekJS непонятная у вас система... а как вы удаляете что-либо кликом по кнопке в модальном окне? Добавьте работающий пример

Comment: Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/9f5kjpwv/19/
Нужно по нажатию кнопки "Да" в модальном окне, получать data-user-id каждой записи

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.btn-delete').click(function(e) {
        console.log($(this).data('user-id'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-delete popup-open" data-user-id="<?= $user['id']; ?>" >Удалить</button>
</td>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-delete').forEach(button => {
//    button.onclick = e => {
//        console.log(e.target.dataset.userId);
//    }
    button.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.dataset.userId);
    }
});
```

```html
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-delete popup-open" data-user-id="<?= $user['id']; ?>" >Удалить</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, поменяйте `$('#btn-delete')` на `$('.btn-delete')`.
Во-вторых, попробуйте следующий код:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.btn-delete').click(function(e) {
        console.log($(e.current).data('user-id'));
    });
});
```

Либо

```
$('document').ready(function() {
      $('.btn-delete').click(function(e) {
         console.log($(e.currentTarget).data('user-id'));
    });
});
```